# enterprise search engine deployment asking for advice

Tags: search, search-server

I am asked to either deploy or develop an enterprise (intranet) search engine which could index all web pages of a couple of internal servers, and have a search portal to display all related content, like what Google is doing but for intranet.

Any advice how to develop or deploy quickly? I have heard of Microsoft FAST product, not sure whether it is for this purpose?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at [Google Search Appliance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html):

> The Google Search Appliance (GSA)
>   provides fast, relevant search for
>   your website or intranet. An
>   on-premise, easy-to-deploy solution,
>   the GSA provides your organization
>   with high relevancy right out of the
>   box, can be customized to meet your
>   specific needs, and scales easily as
>   your content grows.

Don't know about its pricing (and your budget) but may fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I see in a few other posts that you are working with SharePoint, which does an excellent job on Intranet search out of the box.  More information here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.01.search.aspx and http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/default.aspx